# rails 4 date_select helper custom Thai calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, ruby-on-rails-4, helper

I'm using rails 4 to create an application. And in a form I use date_select helper to help user select their birth date. I can change the months name to Thai which is no problem. But I was wondering if there is a way to display years according to Thai calendar which would be 543 years more than Christian calendar. For example if this year is 2015 Thai year would be 2015+543 = 2558 , if the year is 1991 that Thai year would be 1991+543=2534. Please I really want to know if it can be done :). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Rails built in I18n support. Create a locale file for the Thai language `config/locales/th.rb` and override the default date format. If you already have a `th.yml` file you'll have to convert it to a Ruby hash and rename the file to `th.rb` for this to work:

```
{
  th: {
    date: {
      formats: {
        default: lambda { |date, _| "%d.%m.#{date.year + 543}" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now as long as your locale is set to `th` the default date will show the current year plus 543:

```
I18n.locale = :th
puts I18n.l(Date.current) #=> "04.14.2558"
```